# Virtualbox Download Guest Additions Failed with: Unkown Reason

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and installed Virtualbox using `apt-get`. VirtualBox version: 6.0.14_Ubuntu r132055

I have repeatedly tried to click Install Guest Additions and it keeps on telling me it failed with Unknown reason.

Have anyone else seen this problem before? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is this a kali version or you simply used the desktop?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The Kali is the guest OS.